# Testing SOAP Web Services in Java

Tags: java, web-services, selenium, apache-axis, soapui

I am just wondering, is there any Java library to test SOAP web services?

Here is my requirement. There is already an existing web service. The web service can be used to create a record in the database by sending number of input parameters along with authentication in the SOAP header. Now I want to test this web service with different combinations of data and assert the data in the database.

It will be handy if there is an API such that I can create my own automated test suite in Java by interacting with that API. I can handle the response and assert the data in database using JDBC and I also need to verify it on the UI Screen using Selenium.

I came across several APIs in this page: http://java-source.net/open-source/web-services-tools

I am not sure whether I can use API Apache Axis2 in my situation or not.

I know we can use SOAP UI but there is not much documentation. https://www.soapui.org/developers-corner/integrating-with-soapui.html

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Here is [groovy-wslite](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite) does what you are looking for. It is a `groovy` based. You should be able to call from `java` too, imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOAP-UI is one of the leading web service testing tools.  We have used it at my company for years and now use it for nightly automated testing of 100's of different web services, both SOAP and REST.

It has a significant user community, including right here on Stack Overflow.  There is good documentation out there although I agree it can be hard to find.

SOAP-UI exposes its object model via Groovy, so you should be able to integrate with custom Java code.  In fact, it [supports JDBC out of the box](https://www.soapui.org/jdbc/getting-started.html), so you might be able to do your database assertions without writing custom Java code.

The tool also provides decent high-level abstractions around different types of requests, thus you do not have to be a developer to author SOAP-UI tests.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I want to test webservices alone I can use SOAP-UI but I want to test the response on webpage. Inside my selenium webdriver scripts I will request the webservice and login to web application and check these values are populated or not.

Comment: Selenium might be more appropriate for end-to-end product testing, but is not a good way to validate your web services.  Selenium is for UI/Functional testing, where SOAP-UI is an integration testing tool.... Think of it this way.  If you use Selenium, you will have to write lots of testing code to navigate the UI and hope that you can trigger each method of your service.  And good luck maintaining the tests when the UI changes.  And when the test fails, you dont know if it was a UI issue or a web service issue.  SOAP-UI lets you target the services directly.  A much better approach.

Comment: We already have a test suite in SOAP-UI. Since my wbservices can be used to create data. I have to do end to end testing with web service and selenium UI. I figured it out that Axis2 ServiceClient API is helpful for my case. But still digging into other possibilities

Comment: Hey EJK, thanks for your suggestion. I am going to use SOAP-UI API. Which will be handy in runnign my SOAP test from Java

Answer (score 1):

you can integrate SoapUI with Selenium.

http://webservices-testing.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-integrate-soap-ui-with-selenium.html